# Record updates are not evaluated in Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, contactbuilder

I am trying to create a Journey to send SMS for contacts in Data Extension. 
I have created a Data Extension and linked it with Contact Builder crating new Attribute Group (Subscriber Key relates to Contact Key).
After creating a draft journey, I wanted to check if the new updates to record are getting captured or not.

In journey, once 1st SMS is sent with a link, I have a script which checks the checkbox field in DE against that record when the contact clicks on the link he received in SMS. So, in journey I had everything setup and while testing it, I manually checked the box for a record to see if its going to a different path from Decision Split, but looks like the Contact Data still shows the field value as 
 False. I am not sure where I am going wrong, is linking data extension with Contact Builder to do with it?

Comment: You need to Contact Data in your decision split which I think you already have. That's the only thing which is needed. Please double check it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason it was not working because, the Mobile numbers present in DE were new to Marketing Cloud org. and needs to be inserted in All Contact before using them in Journey as Contact Data. So, whenever you insert new contacts with mobile numbers in DE also import them in All Contacts mobile list. This does not applies to Emails though.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a decision split, make sure to use Contact Data, not Journey Data. Here's the difference:

> Journey data preserves the state of a contact's data at the moment an
>   entry event fires, facilitating the use of that data throughout a
>   journey. Contact data captures the data values in the event source
>   data extension at the time when Journey Builder evaluates it. Both are
>   uniquely useful in journey creation.

Read more here: 
Journey and Contact Data: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data.htm&type=5

Journey and Contact Data in Decision Splits: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data_decision_splits.htm&type=5

Comment: Off-course I am using Contact Data.

Comment: I figured this out, my Subscriber Key was not matching with Contact Key. It works when they are same.